# What is the difference between getJSON() function and post() function when make a request across domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, cors

I am trying to access a Google Apps Script WebAPI from my website using javascript to pass some value and create an excel file and download it through this API.

I tried 2 following way:

1. Using POST request with $.post.

My values are many. So, at first, I use a POST request with a body is JSON of list values. Browser rejects API response, because of CORS error.

I researched about CORS to understand it. At some topics, I found a solution is the following second way.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxx' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

2. Using GET request with $.getJSON.

I pass JSON of list values to URL parameter and make GET request. It worked fine.

```
    var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/' + api_id + '/exec?' + request_parameter_string;

    $.post(url, payload, function(data, textStatus) {
        // Do something
    }, 'json');

    $.getJSON(url, function(json_result) {
        // Do something
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // Do something
    });
```

What I do not understand is why? Why it works with `getJSON` but not work with `post`?

I think CORS work with both of GET and POST requests. And I checked the response header with Postman. The headers are the same `Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*`.

I think have something is different inside `getJSON` and `post` functions.

*UPDATE: Update POST CORS error message.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54471800/edit to edit/update the question and paste in the exact CORS error message that the browser is logging in the devtools console.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I updated.

Comment: Use the Network pane in browser devtools to examine the request headers for the OPTIONS request that the browser sends. What’s the value of the Access-Control-Request-Headers request header in that OPTIONS request? That OPTIONS request is a CORS preflight that the browser does before even trying the POST from your code — but your browser wouldn’t be doing doing that preflight OPTIONS unless your code were adding one or more custom headers to the POST request.

Answer (score -1):

`GET` requests are not bound by CORS we can host images and static files in CDN which is different from the origin and would help in improving the performance by caching and making parallel requests.

Similarly `GET` is used for serving ads, trackers and analytics from third party domains as well.

More information about Same Origin Policy and GET is at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/16221/9517

How the browsers identify Other HTTP Verbs are allowed for the cross origin request is elaborated @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: To who ever downvoted the answer, please explain why it is downvoted.